# get img src string portion between 2 items

Tags: jquery, regex

using the example here

```
<img src="site.com/player_photos_big_2014/11247_thumb.jpg" class="articlepicture">
<img src="site.com/player_photos_big_2014/5666_thumb.jpg" class="articlepicture">
<img src="site.com/player_photos_big_2014/76893_thumb.jpg" class="articlepicture">
```

I'm wanting to get the digits of "11247" , "5666" , "76893"

Tried this and didn't work , the image thumb names are different and could be 3 to 5 numerical numbers

```
var test= $('.articlepicture').attr('src')
test.match(/player_photos_big_2014/(.+?)_thumb.jpg)[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexp `\/(\d+)` to match the `/123456` part and `(\d+)` to extract the number part

```js
const result = [];
document.querySelectorAll('img.articlepicture').forEach(img => {
  const n = (img.getAttribute('src').match(/\/(\d+).*\.jpg$/) || ['',''])[1];
  result.push(n);
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<img src="site.com/player_photos_big_2014/11247_thumb.jpg" class="articlepicture">
<img src="site.com/player_photos_big_2014/5666_thumb.jpg" class="articlepicture">
<img src="site.com/player_photos_big_2014/76893_thumb.jpg" class="articlepicture">
```

Comment: how can i get the "n" value again , outside of the function it wont work , anything i place inside the function wont work

Comment: @MShack, revised code. Use an array to store the values.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `split("/").at(-1)` to get the last string (11247_thumb.jpg), then use `replace("_thumb.jpg", "")` to get just the number as a string, lastly; if you want it as an int, use `parseInt()` or `Number()`

All combined should look something like this:

```js
let playerNum = parseInt($(".articlepicture").attr("src").split("/").at(-1).replace("_thumb.jpg", ""))
console.log(playerNum)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="site.com/player_photos_big_2014/11247_thumb.jpg" class="articlepicture">
```

Of course this will only work if the filenames are consistent though!

Comment: this will not work in mobile IOS

Comment: Interesting... Did you make sure to add jQuery? Another possible cause could be `.at()`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
test.match(\/player_photos_big_2014\/(.+?)_thumb\.jpg)[1]
```

Some characters must be escaped

Also, you can test your regex with some sites like this, they are really cool: https://regex101.com

Comment: that kicked back an error in console , thanks though , i think the above answers have it covered